# How do I change the cells in column (in datagrid)

Tags: wpfdatagrid

xaml :

```
 <dg:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FF484040" BorderBrush="#FF484040" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeadersVisibility="Column" Height="195" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="21,12,52,105" Name="dataGrid" SelectedIndex="-1" Width="399">
            <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdBook}" Header=" IdBook" ></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NameBook}" Header="NameBook"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Author}" Header="Author"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DateRegister}" Header="DateRegister"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" Width="*"></dg:DataGridTextColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="15">
                    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Height="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Name="Checkbox" ToolTip="select" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="15" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        </dg:DataGrid>
```

How do I change the cells in column 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the number of columns in the data source. You can get the number of columns in the grid using:

```
MessageBox.Show(dataGrid.Columns.Count.ToString());
```

Comment: How do I change the cells in column 7 ?

Comment: @mrJack: You don't have any data binding in that column, so I'm not sure that is possible. You should add a data binding, then you can just change the value in the data source and the grid is updated.